# Is there any way to run hive query in HDInsight cluster from angularJS?

Tags: angular, apache-spark, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I have a spark cluster in HDInsight where I created some hive tables, now I want to run hive queries from angularJS based on user input for example.
 **Select * from hivesampleTable where id=#input will come from angularUI#**

Comment: Are you expecting that the Angular make a direct call to Hive to fetch data rather going through the service layer? Do you have 2 tier architecture?

Comment: Look into using Spark ThiftServer or Apache Livy

Comment: Yes I want to make a direct call from angular.